# connect two networks though common computer using route table

Tags: linux, networking, route

i have two computers.

computer A network devices:

```
dev   address
-------------
wlan0 192.168.1.2
eth0  10.42.0.1
```

computer A routing table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
10.42.0.0       10.42.0.1       255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

computer B network devices:

```
dev   address
-------------
eth0  10.42.0.2
```

computer B routing table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.42.0.1       0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
```

So computers A and B are connected via ethernet through a switch and computer A is connected to another network (192.168.1.0) though a wireless router (192.168.1.1). I thought this setup would connect the two networks.

On computer B, I try to ping the wireless router

```
ping 192.168.1.1
```

I'm running iptraf on computer A and I can see the request being routed through computer A

```
ICMP echo req (84 bytes) from 10.42.0.2 to 192.168.1.1 on eth0
```

but there is no response.

I thought I understood the route table but I guess I was wrong. Please help!

EDIT:

I added an entry in the wireless router routing table:

```
Destination LAN IP Subnet Mask    Gateway      Interface
0.0.0.0            255.255.255.0  x.x.x.x       WAN (Internet)
0.0.0.0            0.0.0.0        x.x.x.1       WAN (Internet)
10.42.0.0          255.255.255.0  192.168.1.2   LAN & Wireless
x.x.x.0            255.255.252.0  x.x.x.x       WAN (Internet)
192.168.1.0        255.255.255.0  192.168.1.1   LAN & Wireless
```

and that appears to have done the trick! it works now, thanks garethTheRed

Comment: what does `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` show?

Comment: net.ipv4.ip_forward = 0. should it be 1?

Comment: Oh yes :-) Run `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` as root and try again.

Comment: ok did that, but I still cant ping the wireless router (192.168.1.1) from computer B. however, there are two other devices on the wireless network and I can ping one but not the other. (both can be pinged from computer A). very confused

Comment: Do these devices have a firewall? Also, you'll need to have a static route on the router that sends traffic for computer B to computer A, otherwise it will send it down your wireless device's default route.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check the firewall... I did add a route to the wireless router and put it in the edit above. and it works now! so I guess it was the wireless router settings! Thanks!

Comment: @chuck1 Please do not add an **answer** to the question as an **edit** of the question. When you do that it looks like the question remains unanswered. Please provide **answers** to questions as **answers**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added an entry in the wireless router routing table:

```
Destination LAN IP Subnet Mask    Gateway      Interface
0.0.0.0            255.255.255.0  x.x.x.x       WAN (Internet)
0.0.0.0            0.0.0.0        x.x.x.1       WAN (Internet)
10.42.0.0          255.255.255.0  192.168.1.2   LAN & Wireless
x.x.x.0            255.255.252.0  x.x.x.x       WAN (Internet)
192.168.1.0        255.255.255.0  192.168.1.1   LAN & Wireless
```

and that appears to have done the trick! it works now, thanks garethTheRed